# TeamCity : How to define build and deployment steps for database objects

Tags: database, continuous-integration, teamcity

I am currently working on a continuous integration project to auto build and deploy database changes to target environment.
We are using Perforce P4 for source code repository, Nexus for artefacts repository and MS SQL 2008. 
We are not using Redgate for the database repository.

**Check-in process** 
- Developers manually extract database objects (e.g. table, stored proc, function) using Management Studio and check-in to the source repository of Perforce.

**Requirement:**

As part of the CI process, when developers check-in their code to the source repository, the build process should get triggered and create artefacts of checked-in code and get copied to the artefacts repository.

The deployment process should get automatically triggered when it finds any new artefacts and deploy the artefact to the target environment.

I would highly appreciate if someone helps me to know :

build and deployment steps

requirement of manifest file

if it is possible to extract incremental changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get ssdt in visual studio (express works if you don't have licenses)

This will mean your developers check in create statements and you deploy incremental changes, it is pretty simple to setup just have a build step call sqlpackage.exe to deploy or generate scripts